# LINQ Aggregate For Dates

Tags: c#, linq

I've the following inputs:

collection of A: `List<A>`
where A is:

```
class A
{
    DateTime Date;
   int Value;
}
```

the collection represents a range of dates with values, I want to get back a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>`, where `Key` is the first day of each week, included into the range and `Value` is the `Sum` of all `Value` for that week. Ideally I'd like to have the felxibility of specifying the first day of the week.

I'm looking for a solution, using `lamda` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var results = yourList.GroupBy(x => GetFirstDayOfWeek(x.Date))
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.Value));

// ...

private static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dt)
{
    // left as an exercise for the reader!
}
```